# comparing two directories and getting the output with absolute path

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

was trying to compare two directories. one directory is the reference directory(dir1) and the other is the directory where modifications(dir2) are being done

I need the list of files which are modified or added in the dir2 compared with dir1.

I used rsync and diff and getting the result. But need the files with absolute Path in the output.

> diff --brief --recursive /test/dir2 /reference/dir1

Output is

> Only in /test/dir2: king.txt
>
> Only in /test/dir2/sdir2: abc.txt
>
> Only in /test/dir2: test1
>
> Only in /test/dir2/sdir3: test.txt

and using rsync

> rsync -av --dry-run /test/dir2/ /reference/dir1

output

> sending incremental file list
>
> ./
>
> king.txt
>
> test.txt
>
> sdir2/
>
> sdir2/abc.txt
>
> test1/
>
> sent 52712 bytes received 1339 bytes 108102.00 bytes/sec
>
> total size is 0 speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)

need the list with the complete path /test/dir2/king.txt and to be stored in one file.

Best Regards,
KJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be easy enough to tweak the diff output to match your needs ... just pipe the diff through sed.

```
sed -r -e 's/^.*Only in //' -e 's@: @/@'
```

Comment: Hi Tink,

Thanks, this also gave the output with absolute path with extra "/" in the output if the command ends with "/" at the end of directory

Output:

> /test/dir2//king.txt

If the command doesnot have any "/" at the end of directory the output was perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You could just parse the output of `diff`:

```
diff --brief --recursive /test/dir2/ /reference/dir1/ | 
  gawk '(/Only/){print $3""$NF}' | sed 's/://'
```

Make sure you include the trailing `/` in the directory names, this solution expects them. Use `/test/dir2/` and not `/test/dir2`. Also, this will not work if your file names contain spaces.

Comment: Hi terdon,

Thanks for the input. This worked and gave me the absolute path.

Comment: @user2119462 you're welcome. If one of the answers here helped you, please accept and/or upvote it.